# Validation CSV fields RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, csv

What is the best way to make validation fields in a CSV file?
I have CSV file something like
name;surname;postalCode;telephoneNumber
I want to check if the data are correct, if it can be added to the database. What is the best way to start writing it?

Comment: Are you worried about bad data being written to the CSV file or the csv file becoming corrupted in transit?

Answer (score 1):

Write the validation in the model you are saving it to. And then use an `after_save` call to port to the CSV

```
validate :name
validate :telephone
validate :telephone

after_save :make_csv

def make_csv
   your_csv_magic_call()
end
```

Comment: No you don't understand I import csv file and I have to check the correct of all fields and after it add to database

Comment: But what if it doesn't validate appropriately, what would you like to happen? My reasoning is to save it to a data object which Rails has built-in validation for. If that fails then it doesn't import the CSV.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, why would you process the csv file on the after_save callback when the csv file is supplying the data that needs to be validated. Please elaborate.